# Can we run scala script when we execute sbt commands?

Tags: scala, sbt

Whenever we use sbt commands like "sbt compile" or "sbt assembly", i want to run a script.

Is there anyway to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you give minimal example of kind of script you would like to run?

Comment: i want to read  the project source files and check for certain comments and generate report(update readme file) from it

Answer (score 0):

Appending steps to tasks is done similar to the following:

```
compile <<= (compile in Compile) map {result =>
  // whatever you want to do after compile here.
  result
}
```

If you want to define a custom `Command` that runs your script then define a command in your build similar to

```
def myCommand = Command.command("myCommand") { state =>
  s"<relative path to script here>" !; state
}
```

You would then add `myCommand` to each of the tasks that you would like `myCommand` to run after.